# react-native + native-base. Make MapView fill <Content> area

Tags: react-native, native-base

I am using react-native + native-base and am using a simple layout - header content footer. I am using a MapView in the  section and I would like for the Map to fill the Content area. If I specify a width and height in the style of the MapView the map shows up fine. If I set the styles of the MapView to flex : 1 the map does not show up

Here is my code .. All I want is for the Map to fill the Content ..

```js
/**
 * Sample React Native App
 * https://github.com/facebook/react-native
 * @flow
 */

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View, 
  MapView
} from 'react-native';
import { Container, Header, Title, Content, Footer, FooterTab, Button, Icon } from 'native-base';

class Project extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
            <Container> 
                <Header>
                    <Title>TEST</Title>
                </Header>

                <Content>
                    <MapView
                      style={styles.map}
                      showsUserLocation={true}
                    />
                </Content>

                <Footer>
                    <FooterTab>
                        <Button transparent>
                            <Icon name='ios-call' />
                        </Button>  
                    </FooterTab>
                </Footer>
            </Container>
        );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
  welcome: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10,
  },
  instructions: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#333333',
    marginBottom: 5,
  },
  map:{
    flex:1
  }
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('Project', () => Project);
```

Comment: NativeBase will get back to you with a solution for this.

Comment: Did you find the answer? Same problem here, and in android 4.4, real device for genymotion, the header won't appear

Comment: No i did not find the answer

Answer (score 5):

Try wrapping your `<MapView>` in a `<View>` instead of `<Content>`:

```
<View style={{flex: 1}}>
<MapView
  style={styles.map}
  showsUserLocation={true}/>
</View>
```

Answer (score 0):

Native Base Container is a scrollable view, so you cannot fill the map within this container. If you inspect the map element, the height is 0.

One possible solution is detect the window dimension, then calculate the width and height in your code. But be careful about the window frame resize or rotation.

`import Dimensions from 'Dimensions';
Dimensions.get('window').height;
Dimensions.get('window').width;`

Answer (score 0):

I have as below :

```
<Container> 
<Header> 
<Title> My Map</Title> 
</Header> 

<Map />

<Container>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add map inside  component of nativebase, you can use like :

```
<Container> 
   <Header>
      <Title> Map </Title> 
   </Header>

  <Content contentContainerStyle={{ flex: 1 }}> 
      <MapView style={{flex: 1}} />
  </Content> 

   <Footer>
      <FooterTab>
         <Button transparent>
            <Icon name='ios-call' />
         </Button>  
       </FooterTab>
    </Footer>

</Container>
```